# Changes in the variable are not sent

Tags: angular

i have a service, component and module.

in the service, which I want to send the changes of **flag$** variable.

```
export class ListUserService {
    public flag$ = new Subject< boolean >();
}
```

This component makes the changes for the variable

```
export class ListUserComponent implements OnInit {
    private flagPerfil = false;

    getFlag() {
        return this.flagPerfil;
    }


  constructor(private listUserService: ListUserService) {

  }

  functionThatGetsCalledWhenTheFlagIsChanged(){
     this.listUserService.flags$.next(this.flagPerfil);
  }
}
```

I need to receive the variable **flag$** in this module:

```
export class Tab1PageModule {
    public flagPerfil: boolean;

    constructor(private listUserService: ListUserService) {
        listUserService.flag$.subscribe((flag)=>{
           console.log('FLAG', flag); //never show the console
           this.flagPerfil = flag;
      });
    }
}
```

never enters this console `console.log('FLAG', flag);` but ocurs this error **TS2322:Type 'Subject' is not assignable to type 'boolean'**, and in the view of the module nothing is displayed

```
<ion-card-title> {{flagPerfil}} Puedes agregarlos para iniciar una amistad</ion-card-title>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a behavior subject as they have a default value and any new observers get the last value emitted, subjects only notify observers when they emit, the last value is lost to new observers.

```
export class ListUserService {
  public flag$ = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(false);
}
```

```js
const { Subject, BehaviorSubject } = rxjs;

const subject$ = new Subject();
subject$.next('Subject initial val');
const behaviorSubject$ = new BehaviorSubject('BehaviorSubject initial val');

subject$.subscribe(val => { console.log(val); });
behaviorSubject$.subscribe(val => { console.log(val); });

subject$.next('Subject new val');
behaviorSubject$.next('BehaviorSubject new val');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/6.4.0/rxjs.umd.min.js"></script>
```

And use the async pipe in your component so you don't need to subscribe in the code.

```
export class ListUserComponent implements OnInit {
  flags$ = this.listUserService.flags$;


  constructor(private listUserService: ListUserService) {

  }

  functionThatGetsCalledWhenTheFlagIsChanged(value: boolean){
     this.listUserService.flags$.next(value);
  }
}
```

and in the view template

```
<ion-card-title> {{flag$ | async}} Puedes agregarlos para iniciar una amistad</ion-card-title>
```

Comment: now if show the console, but the variable never show in the view of module <ion-card-title> {{flagPerfil}} Puedes agregarlos para iniciar una amistad</ion-card-title>

Comment: the view belong to module, and see this console console.log('', this.listUserService.flag$);  // BehaviorSubject {_isScalar: false, observers: Array(0), closed: false, isStopped: false, hasError: false, …}